# Coefficient of Performance and Sign Convention

Tags: thermodynamics, work, conventions

I am using the sign convention: Heat absorbed by the system is positive and heat left the system is negative. Work done on the system is positive and work done by the system is negative. It was super consistent and I was able to do all calculations (basically, writing every parameter as plus and distributing the negatives if they are done by/leaving the system) since it is very logical. However, I can't find the formula for same convention when it comes to thermal efficiency and Coefficient of Performance (COP) for heat pumps and refrigerators. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: As far as I know, the formulas for the COPs for refrigerators and heat pumps are for the magnitude of the COP. If you considered the signs for work and heat, the COP for the heat pump would be positive and the COP for the refrigerator would be negaitve.